# Listing Servers - OpenStack Nova API

Tags: python, openstack, cherrypy, openstack-nova, keystone

I've passed the session object from another class (using Cherrypy cookies) and rebuilt the Nova instance in this class to list the servers. The rebuilt Nova instance works however when I try and create a list of servers, I have an attribute error. There's very little (I found nothing remotely like this issue) out on the internet about this sort of issue. 
How do I solve this issue? :)

Code:

```
import cherrypy
import xmlrpclib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from keystoneauth1 import loading
from keystoneauth1 import session
import novaclient.client as client
from socket import gethostbyaddr

nova = client.Client("2.1", session=cherrypy.request.cookie.get('sessCookie').value)
serverList = nova.servers.list()
print serverList
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py", line 61, in json_handler
    value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/var/www/frontend/controllers/api/vm.py", line 158, in GET
    serverList = nova.servers.list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v2/servers.py", line 749, in list
    "servers")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 242, in _list
    resp, body = self.api.client.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 173, in get
    return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 89, in request
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 331, in request
    resp = super(LegacyJsonAdapter, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 98, in request
    return self.session.request(url, method, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `session` keyword is supposed to be a Keystone `session` object, but you're passing in a string.

You can read more about working with Keystone sessions [here](https://docs.openstack.org/python-keystoneclient/latest/using-sessions.html).

Comment: As in I'm passing 'sessCookie' which is being classed as a string? I'm rather new to this, so apologies for my incompetence, cheers Matt :)

Comment: Yes, it appears that you are trying to pass in a string where you actually need to pass in a session object.  You could of course verify that by, for example, using the Python debugger to inspect the value of `cherrypy.request.cookie.get('sessCookie').value`, but since cookies are generally strings this seems like a safe bet.

Comment: I think I understand your point but when I do:
`cherrypy.request.cookie.get('name').value`, it gets the value inside the cookie called 'name'. So the same should be done with sessCookie? 
I have passed the session object doing the following if that helps:
`cherrypy.response.cookie['sessCookie'] = sess`

Comment: Cookies, in general, are just strings of text that are stored in your browser.  I don't think you'll be able to use cookies to transfer a Python object like that.

Comment: Now I understand what you're saying :) so what alternatives do I have to store the session object so it can be 'passed' to other classes/methods to be used elsewhere?